# Changing Default Button Highlighting WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I am trying to remove the default background on a `Button`, but then highlight the `Button` in orange when the user hovers over the button with their mouse. This is what I have come up with so far;

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

However, when the user mouses over the button it is highlighted in the default blue still, instead of the orange I would like. How can I modify this so that the Button's text is gradually highlighted in orange?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `ControlTemplate.Trigger`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
 <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
 <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
 <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="30" />
 <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
 <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
 <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
       <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
          <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
             <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
          </Border>
           <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" 
                          Value="True">
                   <Setter Property="Background" 
                           Value="Orange"/>
                </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
       </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
```