# How to set some type of highlight to a button when it's default button or when it's mouse over button?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles

Here is a button which I styled, but I realized that there is no way for someone who uses the application to notice when button is mouse over / selected or something like that?
I just want some kind of notification when button is selected or whatever?
Any kind of solution will be acceptable for me so in case button is mouse hovered, or in case button is selected to notice user
that is that button!

Here is my current button:

```
 <Button x:Name="btnOk"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    UseLayoutRounding="True"
                    IsDefault="True"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    FontSize="15"
                    Width="140"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    Foreground="#0091EA"
                    Background="White"
                    Content="Ok!"
                    BorderBrush="#0091EA" Margin="5,10,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="btnPotvrdi_Click">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="BlueViolet"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>

            </Button.Template>

        </Button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Default Button Highlighting WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39118429/changing-default-button-highlighting-wpf)

Comment: @NeerajKumar it's not duplicate, I applied solution from that link but it is not working so obliviously something is wrong in my code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the default background (`White`) in the `Style` and your trigger will work as expected:

```
<Button x:Name="btnOk"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    UseLayoutRounding="True"
                    IsDefault="True"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    FontSize="15"
                    Width="140"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    Foreground="#0091EA"
                    Content="Ok!"
                    BorderBrush="#0091EA" Margin="5,10,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="btnPotvrdi_Click">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="BlueViolet"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

A "local" value takes precedence over a value set by a `Setter` in a `Style`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: in fact my example was good, but I had issue cuz I didnt put background property in my Button.Style so button was white all the time and I couldn't see changes

Comment: and btw how could I on first enter click while window with button is opened just select button without firing the trigger so in fact user should hit enter twice to hit trigger btnOk

Comment: Please don't ask additional questions in the comments field. Ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: I tried changing datetime on my comp but someone made this site good damn :/ xD